# Point transformation of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems

I am trying to understand a passage in the introduction to [this book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Qd4YeHCR5pcC&lpg=PA277&ots=cRCX4C2ggs&dq=fiber%20preserving%20transformation&hl=fr&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=fiber%20preserving%20transformation&f=false), which deals with algorithmical procedures to analytically solve ODEs. Specifically, I do not understand how the ODE 
$$
y''(y+x) + y'(y'-1)=0, \quad y=y(x)$$
(formula (1.1) in the linked page) is transformed into 
$$
2v'' u + (v')^2 - 1 =0 \quad v=v(u)$$
by the point transformation 
$$
x=u+v \qquad y=u-v.$$
This should be easy. However, the fact that the transformation is not *fiber-preserving* is confusing to me. (By fiber-preserving I mean that the independent variable $x$ is not a function of the independent variable $u$ alone).

Also, the given reference is in German and I cannot read that language.

**EDIT**. I found a good explanation of the theoretical aspects of this kind of transformations in Olver's book *Applications of Lie groups to differential equations*, §2.2 "Groups and differential equations".

Comment: The advice given by J. Michael Steele in the small subsection "Organizing Computations" (*Stochastic calculus and financial applications*, pag. 186) is also useful here. It has been reproduced (with some changes) in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables_%28PDE%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle u=\frac{x+y}{2}$, $\displaystyle v=\frac{x-y}{2}$. Then $\displaystyle \frac{dv}{du}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{du}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{1}{1+y'}-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{y'}}=\frac{2}{y'+1}-1$, $\displaystyle \frac{d^2v}{du^2}=\frac{-2}{(y'+1)^2}\frac{dy'}{du}=\frac{-2}{(y'+1)^2}y''\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{-4}{(y'+1)^2}y''\frac{1}{1+y'}=\frac{-4}{(y'+1)^3}y''=\frac{-2}{(y'+1)^3}\frac{y'(1-y')}{u}\implies 2v''u=\frac{-4}{(y'+1)^3}y'(1-y')$.

Now just make the proper substitutions for $y'$ from $\displaystyle \frac{dv}{du}$.

Comment: I thank you very much for your answer. I would like some clarifications. Unfortunately I am not conversant with those manipulations of infinitesimals and I cannot understand the line $$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{du} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{du}= \frac{1}{1+y'}-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{y'}}.$$ I understand that the first identity is the chain rule and that the second is found by differentiating the equations $u=\frac{x+y}{2}, v=\frac{x-y}{2}$ and substituting into the fractions $\frac{dx}{du}, \frac{dy}{du}$.

Comment: What I fail to understand is why some differentials are partial and the others are total. For instance, I obtain the following absurd result: $$\frac{dv}{du}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=0, $$which is clearly nonsense. Why is this wrong?

Comment: (P.S.: I guess ther's a sign error and $\frac{2}{y'+1}+1$ really should be $\frac{2}{y'+1}-1$.)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes you are right about the sign, I fixed it. The reason some of the derivative are partials and some are total is just because that is how chain rule works. What you wrote would be write if you were taking $\frac{\partial v}{\partial u}$, and in this case you should, as you did, get $0$.

Comment: And what exactly is the difference between partial and total, here? I am sorry to bother you, but the only context in which I have seen such a distinction is in fluid mechanics, where a "partial" derivative is Eulerian and a "total" is Lagrangian. I do not see how to apply this distinction here.