# How do I learn to stop worrying and love the substitution $y'' = y' (dy'/dy)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, inverse-function-theorem

The following is a solution of the differential equation $y'' = y$ with initial values $y(0) = 3$, $y'(0) = 1$. Considering $y$ to be a function of $x$ and omitting some standard details:

> Let $z = y'$. Then $y'' = \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} = z \frac{dz}{dy}$. Substituting, $z\frac{dz}{dy} = y$ is separable with initial value $y = 3$, $z = 1$, so has the unique solution $z = \sqrt{y^2 - 8}$. Now the equation $y' = \sqrt{y^2 - 8}$ with initial value $y(0) = 3$ has solution $y = 2e^x + e^{-x}$, which is also a solution to the original problem.

While this does produce the correct answer, the step using $\frac{dz}{dy}$ is unjustified. One way to fill this gap is to note that since $y'(0) \ne 0$, the inverse function theorem says that locally $x$ and therefore $y'$ is in fact a (smooth) function of $y$. This is somewhat implicitly used in picking the positive branch of the square root $\sqrt{y^2 - 8}$.

But I do not know how to justify the definition of $z$ as a function of $y$ and therefore of $\frac{dz}{dy}$ if you change the initial values to something like $y(0) = 2$, $y'(0) = 0$. The solution does have $y$ an *invertible* function of $x$ but this is not known *a priori*. If you just blindly work through the integration without worrying you still get the solution $y(x) = e^x + e^{-x}$, no matter which branch of the square root $\pm \sqrt{y^2 - 4}$ you pick (and in fact $y'$ changes sign near $x = 0$, so neither of these is valid even locally).

**Is there a way to make this work rigorously?** Or are there similar equations and initial values where this substitution misses a solution? I'm not so worried about it introducing extraneous solution although I do not have an example of that either.

I originally learnt this solution in high school from a physics-y book that did not justify the differentiability, as is usual in high school level physics-y books. Actually in that book the original solution was for the simple harmonic motion equation $y'' = -\omega^2 y$ but, as I noticed later, the same substitution seems to help with some other second order ODEs too.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/812800/8157) is loosely related, hope it helps (I am not sure it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manipulation ultimately ends up being the ODE $yy' = y' y''$ in disguise which is of trivially statisfied by any solution to the original ODE. Separating variables on the equivalent (for nonzero $y$) $y' = \frac{y' y''}{y}$ then results in solving $y' = (y' y'') \frac{1}{y}$ where $y'y''$ is the term you'd integrate over $x$ and $\frac{1}{y}$ the one to integrate over $y$. So using the "less problematic" version of separation of variables you just integrate $y y' = y' y''$ over $x$:
$$
\textbf{LHS:} \quad \int y y' dx = \int y dy = \frac{y^2}{2} 
\\
\textbf{RHS:} \quad \int y' y'' dx = \int y' dy' = \frac{y'^2}{2} + C.
$$
Together we thus get the new ODE $y^2 = y'^2 + C$ which we can easily solve (you can find that $C=8$ by plugging in the initial conditions).

So basically you can avoid the whole substitution by first working things through with it, and then just eliminating it in a way that avoids all potentially undefined or problematic quantities.

Comment: What is the motivation for your separation? It is un-done in the next step and serves no obvious purpose. This also seems like something a clueless AI would do. And in the integration the integration constants are missing.

Comment: What do you mean with it being "undone"? Because the $y$ is multiplied back over? That's to avoid division by $y$ and to setup the separation according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Alternative_notation

No AI would do it this way and neither would I FWIW if we just wanted to solve the original ODE - you can read off the solution right from the beginning / use the normal $\exp(rx)$ ansatz. The purpose of my answer was to keep OPs basic path while avoiding the potentially problematic bits.

I added the missing constant.

Comment: There is no division in the original equation. There is no division after multiplication with $y'$. From there you can directly integrate. Why do you want to separate something that was just carefully put together? Where do you integrate $\frac1y$ over $y$? Is that some partial integration you tried?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want or mean with your comment.

The only division in my answer is to show OP that their manipulation yields something equivalent to what we get by multiplying by $y'$, except that the multiplication is also valid when $y$ is zero. There is no partial integration, it's just multiplying by $y'$ and integrating directly which yields the same as plugging $g=y'y'', h(y)=1/y$ corresponding to OPs solution into the separation theorem.

Where would you integrate $\frac{1}{y}$ here? It doesn't come up anywhere.

Comment: Except, there is no separation theorem for second order DE. If you make $zz'=y$ explicit to $z'=\frac{y}{z}$, then you divide by $z=y'$, not $y$.

Comment: are you saying all equations where this substitution is useful can be instead solved using some kind of integrating factor? This is not implausible but I don't think this answer has enough evidence.

Comment: Yes, every solution where $y'=z(y)$ is used can be reverse engineered to not need this substitution. With it the solution steps can be easier to detect, but the reworked solution will be as easy to read.

Comment: @ronno Certain equations that are separable "in $z=y'$" are solvable without referring to $z$ explicitly is what I'm saying. If your equation is of the form $h(y')y'' = g(y)y'$ (note how this translates to separability with the $z$ substitution and by replacing $h(y')$ with $h_1(y') = \frac{1}{h(y')}$), you can eliminate $y''$ using the usual integration.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of intro differential equations just do nonsense or make large assumptions in order to get the answer. It’s oftentimes much easier to do something non-rigorous to get the solutions and then use standard uniqueness/existence theorems (i.e. checking for singularities) on them to prove they’re the full set of solutions rather than maintain rigor throughout the initial calculation, keeping track of every time you assume a derivative is nonzero and where you’ve used various higher level theorems to justify it.

Comment: I agree that coming up with a guess somehow and checking that it satisfies the equation is a valid strategy for solving differential equations but that doesn't mean that there isn't a rigorous version of the "trick" in the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you are worrying about the fact that $y'(0) =0$ just remember that since the function is differential for all real $x$. The limit converged to a constant term. Here we are taking in terms of limit. If you solve it using basic calculus or using definition of differentiation, you will get the same result.

Comment: Where in the question are limits mentioned?

Comment: Of course $y$ is a differentiable function of $x$ but it is not at all clear that $y'$ is a differentiable function or even a function of $y$.

Comment: @ronno : That is quite easy to analyze. If $y'=0$ on some segment of non-zero length, then the whole solution is constant, its value an equilibrium point of the DE. Otherwise $y(x)$ can be subdivided in segments where it is strictly raising or strictly falling, thus the inverse function exists, for each segment separately. Your question is about the interesting case that the initial condition is given on a segment boundary.

Answer (score -1):

One way to think about this is to view the introduction of $z=y'$ as switching from considering a $1$-dimensional initial value problem (of second order) to a $2$-dimensional initial value problem (of first order). In other words, I can consider a vector-valued first order problem, $\mathbf x(t) = (x_1(t),x_2(t))$ satisfies
$$
\mathbf x'(t) = \left(\begin{array}{c} x_1'(t)\\ x_2'(t) \end{array}\right) =  \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c} x_1(t)\\ x_2(t) \end{array}\right)
$$
Since $x_1'(t)=x_2$ and $x_2'(t)=x_1$, the first component of any solution of this vector-valued ODE will satisfy $x_2''(t)=x_2$. Conversely any solution $y(t)$ to the original ODE will yield a solution of the vector-valued ODE, namely $\mathbf x(t) =(y(t),y'(t))^T$.

Viewing things through the first-order vector-valued ODE, you don't have to take any special consideration into account when $y'(0)=0$, it is just like any other vector-valued initial condition.

By transposing the problem to a vector-valued setting,the initial value problem becomes one of the form $\mathbf x'(t) = F(\mathbf x(t))$, where $F\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$. In the example above, $F$ is the linear map $F(\mathbf x) = (x_2,x_1)^T$. You can use the chain rule $etc.$ to $F(\mathbf x(t))$ without having to think of one coordinate being a function of the other (which you can do using the implicit function theorem, as you point out, most, *but not all* of the time along a solution curve - moving to the vector-valued problem, however, there is no need to).

The separation of variables technique in the vector-valued problem is then just noting that as $x_1'(t)=x_2$ and $x_2'(t)=x_1$, we have $x_1x_1' = x_2x_2'$, or $\frac{d}{dt}(x_1^2-x_2^{2})=0$, and hence $x_1^2=C+x_2^2$.

Indeed, you can go a little further and see what underlies the separation of variable technique here:The the function $g(x)=x_1^2-x_2^2$ has the property that $Dg(x) = (2x_1,-2x_2)$, so that $Dg(x)(F(x)) =0$, that is $x_2\partial_1 g(x) + x_1\partial_2 g =0$. Now rather than thinking of $Dg$ acting on $F$, you can associate to $F$ the vector field $\vartheta =\vartheta_F = x_2\partial_1 + x_1 \partial_2$ then $\vartheta(g)=0$, so the solution curves $\mathbf x(t)$ will lie on the level sets of $g$, as $D(g(\mathbf x(t)) = \vartheta(g)=0$. In general if $F= (f_1,f_2)^T$ then $\vartheta_F = f_1\partial_1+f_2\partial_2$, and solutions to $\mathbf x'(t) = F(\mathbf x)$ will lie on the level sets of functions $g$ that satisfy $\vartheta_F(g)=0$. If you prefer to think in terms of gradients, then $\vartheta_F(g) = \langle F, \nabla_g\rangle$, where $\langle \mathbf x,\mathbf y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^2 x_iy_i$ is the standard dot product.

Finally, the vector-valued formulation also lets you completely solve constant coefficient ODE, or at least reduce the problem to the classification of matrices up to conjugation. Since generically a matrix is diagonalizable, one can generically at least, replace an $n$-th order constant coefficient ODE with $n$ independent $1$st order problems, which are then trivial to solve.  In the case of $y''=y$ above, if I let $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ , so that the differential equation becomes $\mathbf x'(t) = A\mathbf x(t)$, I can solve this with the matrix exponential, so the solution formally looks like the $y'=a.y$ case:
$$
\mathbf x(t) = \exp(tA)\mathbf x(0) \quad \text{ where } \exp(tA) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^nA^n}{n!}.
$$

Viewing $\text{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)$ as an inner product space via $A\cdot B = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}b_{ij} = \text{tr}(A^tB)$, we have $\|A\|:=(\text{tr}(A^tA))^{1/2}$ and $\|AB\|\leq \|A\|.\|B\|$, so the series $\exp(tA)$ is absolutely convergent for all $A\in \text{Mat}_n(\mathbb R)$ and $t \in \mathbb R$. Similarly, it is easy to see that $\frac{d}{dt}\exp(tA) = A\exp(tA)$, so that $\exp(tA).\mathbf x(0)$ does indeed solve the differential equation.

Moreover, since $A$ is in this case symmetric and so diagonalizable, there is a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ -- explicitly in this case we can take the basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ where $v_1 = (e_1+e_2)/\sqrt{2}$ and $v_2 = (e_1-e_2)/\sqrt{2}$ which have eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ respectively, so that $A = PDP^{-1}$ where $$
P= (\mathbf v_1 |\mathbf v_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{array}\right), \quad \text{and }
D= \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right)
$$
If $\mathbf z = P^{-1}\mathbf x$, then as $P$ is orthogonal $P^{-1}=P^T$ which is equal to $P$, so that
$$
 \mathbf z(t) =  \left(\begin{array}{c} z_1(t) \\ z_2(t) \end{array}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1\\ 1 & -1 \end{array}\right)\mathbf x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c} x_1(t)+x_2(t) \\ x_1(t)-x_2(t) \end{array}\right)
$$
then $\mathbf z'(t) = D\mathbf z(t)$, that is, $z_1'(t)=z_1(t)$ and $z_2'(t) = -z_2(t)$. Thus the change of coordinates "decouples" the vector-valued system into two 1-dimensional first order equations. It is not helpful to think of whether $z_2$ can/should be viewed as a function of $z_1$ here, and again the vector-valued problem doesn't care, but some textbooks will say incomprehensible things about replacing $y,y''$ with "independent functions" $u=y+y'$ and $v=y-y'$

Comment: This has nothing to do with the parametrization $y'(x)=z(y(x))$ that is discussed in the question. The last third comes closer if you consider multiplication with $2y'$ (where $y'\ne 0$) and integration $2y'y''=2yy'\implies y'^2=y^2+C$ as alternative to the "trick" in discussion.

Comment: I've tried to tidy this up a little as it probably said too much, but the point of the post is that ``the parametrization $y'(x) = z(y(x))$'' that works even when it it isn't justifiable, as the OP puts it, can be explained by the association of the vector-valued ODE -- there is a natural bijection between the solutions of the two problems, and the vector-valued one is the context in which the separation of variables etc. techniques are easy to make rigorous.

Comment: For example, the "multiplication by $2y'$" trick you describe becomes less arbitrary if you notice that $\langle F,\nabla_g \rangle  = x_2\partial_1g +x_1\partial_2 g=0$ for any function $g(x_1,x_2)$ that satisfies $\partial_1 g = x_1$ and $\partial_2 g=-x_2$, and this is readily integrated to give $g= x_1^2-x_2^2$, hence the solution curves $\mathbf x(t)$ satisfy $x_1^2(t)=x_2^2(t)+g(\mathbf x(0))$.

Comment: Would your first part also supply a motivation for the "trick" if the equation were $y''+p(y)=0$? I'm not sure I understand the last comment. Is that a long-winded way to describe what a first integral is? But the "order reduction" trick is mainly used to find the first integral in the first place.

Comment: I don't see at all how the linear change of variables has to do with the $y' = z(y)$ substitution. I don't think it's so relevant to the substitution that I started with a linear ODE with constant coefficients, that just happened to be the simplest example to work out.

Comment: @ronno: the way to make the "$y'=z(y)$ substitution" rigorous is to realize that you do not need to think of $z$ as a function of $y$ in the first place. That is what the 2-d ODE does for you. I agree that it isn't important that the ODE you started with was linear, but the linear case gives another example: Generically a matrix is diagonalizable, and its eigenvectors give the basis which decouples the system. If these happened to correspond to $z_1=y$ and $z_2 =y+y'$ you don't worry about how to view $z_2$ as function of $y$. In the same way, we don't need $z=y'$ to be a function of $y$.